# How to set amplify cognito login session to access s3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

Okay so I am trying to send something to s3 from my React Native application and I can get it to work when I allow all s3 permissions for the unauth role but I do not want this role to have all permissions. I want the auth user to have all permissions. So when I log in, how can I set that user that is logged in to an auth role?

Do I have to somehow pass the session token to the storage.put() command? I am finding nothing in their documentation.

This is my login function:

```
try {
            const user = await Auth.signIn("test", "12345678");
            console.log(user);
            console.log("SUCCESS");

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
```

And this is my storage.put

```
            const file = await fetch(uri);
            const blob = await file.blob();
            const key = name;

            return Storage.put(key, blob, {
                contentType: type,
            });
        };
```

So like I said, when I give the unauth user full permissions the image uploads just fine. But when I limit the permissions of unauth it gets an error 403 which is great. But how do I get this to be sent from an auth user?

Comment: Any updates? Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @EvanErickson Actually no. I was never able to find this out. However, if you do please please keep me updated. I just continued work allowing unauth access even though I believe this opens a security risk.